# Subdomain redirects to subdirectory

Tags: directory, subdomains

Supposing I have folder called "support" inside root folder "/public_html". I've added a subdomain in my server's panel so that when going to "support.mydomain.com" it redirects to "mydomain.com/support"

The problem is that redirection is reflected on the browser's address bar, and I want to make that subdomain work like "base domain". i.e "support.mydomain.com/folder-inside-support"

Is it something to be with .htaccess file?

Comment: See answer below.  This will redirect to support.example.com/ then on your server, put another folder inside the folder for the subdomain,ie /public_html/support/suport2

Comment: This is clearly a off-topic question.

Comment: Where should I have posted it?

Comment: Use ProWebMasters.SE next time.  There's even an `.htaccess` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.example.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Replace both instances of "example.com" with your domain name.

Taken from: [htaccess Subdomain Redirect](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/htaccess-subdomain-redirect.141756/)